# Plot GeoJSON on top of raster plot

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a GeoJSON file on top of a raster. While different questions have touched this topic, I have not found a specific one addressing the approach I need.

I would prefer using `imshow` rather than `rasterio.show` for this.

```
roi = gpd.read_file('myfile.geojson')
  
roi_geom = []
coord = shapely.geometry.mapping(aoi)["features"][0]["geometry"]
roi_geom.append(coord)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,7))

axs[0].imshow(raster_1) # raster_1.shape = 1935, 1515, 3. Values normalized from 0 to 1

# Add ROI box
patches = [PolygonPatch(feature, edgecolor="red", facecolor="none", linewidth=2) for feature in roi_geom]
ax1.add_collection(cplt.PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True))

axs[1].imshow(raster_2) # raster_2.shape = 1265, 1055, 3). Values normalized from 0 to 1
```

No error is generated when running this code but the `patches` variable, which represents the geometry of a GeoJSON file is not plotted. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
# I think is better If you use rasterio, plot and matplotlib

# Look this code:   


import rasterio 
    
from rasterio import plot

import geopandas as gpd
    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=9,4 # Define size

# Read raster

b1 = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster1)
b2 = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster2)
b3 = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster3)
b4 = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster4)

ba1 = b1.read()
ba2 = b2.read()
ba3 = b3.read()
ba4 = b4.read()


# Read geometry

geojson = gpd.read_file(inputpath_geojson)

# Plot geojson

geojson.plot(color='red')
plt.show()



# Plot raster and geojson

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))

p1  = rasterio.plot.show(b1, ax=ax[0,0], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 1')
p2  = rasterio.plot.show(b2, ax=ax[0,1], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 2')
p3  = rasterio.plot.show(b3, ax=ax[1,0], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 3')
p4  = rasterio.plot.show(b4, ax=ax[1,1], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 3')

geojson.plot(ax=p1, color='red')
geojson.plot(ax=p2, color='red')
geojson.plot(ax=p3, color='red')
geojson.plot(ax=p4, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: My starting point is a 4 band geotiff. How can that be used for your example?

Comment: Create a new variable like this: b4 = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster4)

Comment: I think its not clear on my question actually, but that is how I have it. See the comment in the code where you can see the shape of my raster `raster_1` (1935, 1515, 3). My problem is that having a raster like this, the polygon with the geometry of my geojson does not get plotted